# several hook_cron for one module, drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

does anybody know is it possible (drupal 6) to create several tasks which should run by crontab? I've created hook mymodule_cron but I need one more. Is it possible to create something like mymodule_another_task_cron?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add another task in your existing hook_cron? You can call whatever functions you want from one hook_cron.

Comment: Those tasks should run in different time

Comment: Ahh, ok. Then you'll need another cron hook, in another module, and use another module, like [Elysia](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) to differentiate between different hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend the [Elysia Cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) module

> Elysia Cron extends Drupal standard cron, allowing a fine grain control over each task and several ways to add custom cron jobs to your site.

As a module developer the method you'll be most interested in is implementing `hook_cronapi()` to register jobs that can be scheduled individually through the Elysia cron admin settings.

There's also [Ultimate Cron](http://drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron), but I can't vouch for that one as I've never used it.